# Sagemaker - additional endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, scikit-learn, amazon-sagemaker

I created my own model with scikit learn. Apart from standard endpoints, '/ping' and '/invocations' I added a third one, '/estimates' (it calls predict_probabilities()).

When I run locally container all endpoints work correctly. When I deploy this as endpoint on Sagemaker '/invocations' works correctly. With the same auth token (generated by Postman) calling '/estimates' gives me an error:

```
<AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>
```

I can't even see attempts to call '/estimates' in cloudwatch. 
Is there any way to create 3rd endpoint or should I create another container for this and serve probabilities from '/invocations'?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you were trying to call `https://runtime.sagemaker.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/endpoints/<YOUR_ENDPOINT_NAME>/estimates` when you saw the AccessDeniedException?

If that's the case, it has to do with you making a request against an URL that's not mapped to a SageMaker Runtime API. SigV4 didn't no how to interpret or sign your request without such mappings, so it couldn't authenticate you.

In order to invoke your endpoint, you should always send requests to `https://runtime.sagemaker.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/endpoints/<YOUR_ENDPOINT_NAME>/invocations`. SageMaker always forwards requests to your model container by at the `/invocations` path, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-inference-code.html).

If you are looking to bundle different model behaviors into the same container, I'd suggest including a [CustomAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint.html#API_runtime_InvokeEndpoint_RequestSyntax) in your InvokeEndpoint requests. This header will be passed to your container, which can then respond differently depending on the custom attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a custom container, so it's difficult to know exactly what's going on :)  I've had this problem before: have you tried both GET and POST?

FYI, SageMaker now includes a built-in, open source container for sklearn: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-scikit-learn-container. Maybe that's an easier starting point? :)